# Put something after the nth digit, rather than nth character?

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on an autocomplete for SSN-like numbers in PHP. So if the user searches for '123', it should find the number 444123555. I want to bold the results, thus, `444<b>123</b>555`. I then, however, want to format it as an SSN - thus creating `444-<b>12-3</b>555`.

Is there some way to say 'put the dash after the nth digit'? Because I don't want the nth character, just the nth digit - if I could say 'put a dash after the third digit and the fifth digit, ignoring non-numeric characters like <, b, and >' that would be awesome. Is this doable in a regex?

Or is there a different method that's escaping me here?

Comment: Do you have the search result already, or is getting the search result part of the question? If you have the search functionality already, please describe how it matches. That is needed to match the right part for the highlighting as well.

Comment: I trim dashes on the input and search in a dash-trimmed column in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate over the string and check that each character is a digit and count the digits as you go.

That will be so much faster than regex, even if regex were a feasible solution here (which I am not convinced it is).

Comment: Well, there actually is a very simple (and most likely faster) regex that does exactly what you want. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly what you asked for:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^ ((?:\D*\d){3}) ((?:\D*\d){2}) /x', '$1-$2-', $str);
```

The `(?:\D*\d)` Will match any number of non-digits, then a digit. By repeating that n times, you match n digits, "ignoring" everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function using an iterative approach as Platinum Azure suggests:

```
function addNumberSeparator($numString, $n, $separator = '-')
{
    $numStringLen = strlen($numString);

    $numCount = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $numStringLen; $i++)
    {
        if(is_numeric($numString[$i]))
        {
            $numCount++;
            //echo $numCount . '-' . $i;
        }

        if($numCount == $n)
            return substr($numString, 0, $i + 1) . $separator .     substr($numString, $i + 1);
    }
}

$string = '444<b>123</b>555';

$string = addNumberSeparator($string, 3);
$string = addNumberSeparator($string, 5);

echo $string;
```

This outputs the following:

```
4x<b>x123</b>555
```

That will, of course, only work with a non-numeric separator character. Not the most polished piece of code, but it should give you a start!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get formated number and surrounding text:

```
<?php
preg_match("/(.*)(\d{3})(12)(3)(.*)/", "assd444123666as555", $match);
$str = $match[1];
if($match[2]!=="") $str.=$match[2]."-<b>";
$str.=$match[3]."-".$match[4]."</b>";
if($match[5]!=="") $str.=$match[5];
echo $str;
?>
```

If only formatted number:

```
<?php
preg_match("/(.*)(\d{3})(12)(3)(.*)/", "as444123666as555", $match);
$str = "";
if($match[2]!=="") $str.=$match[2]."-<b>";
$str.=$match[3]."-".$match[4]."</b>";
echo $str;
?>
```

Sorry, but it is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Did you just tell me how to surround the central three digits, regardless of what they are? So what if the 123 is at the start of the string? Or begins at the 4th position? Edit: and your edit doesn't even do that well. You don't seem to have understood the meaning of the question - it was to insert the dashes correctly *no matter where the search result is*. It's not always going to be the middle three. I don't feel this was ambiguous.

Comment: And what of the bolding surrounding the search string?

Comment: How do you want to do that...? By putting this between this symbol: "*"? So, what exactly should be on the output? This? http://pastebin.com/LaQJYakQ

Comment: On my screen I see 444123555 with 123 as bold. Before it was *s because the parser seemed broken. I am replacing the digits with, in this case, `<b>123</b>`. I then want to hyphenate it properly. Sorry that it relied on formatting to be clear.

Comment: OK, now I think I understand everything. Sorry for problems... I edited my answer.